# Storing messages as BLOB (Binary Large Object) or ordinary text?

Tags: mysql, database, text, blob

What is the best way to store messaging texts in large/big web sites: BLOB or ordinary text in table or something else? Database: MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of questions you need to ask yourself when making that decision.  There's a very detailed article, [To BLOB or not to BLOB, that is the question: Whether to store string in BLOB, or CHAR, or VARCHAR?](https://web.archive.org/web/20121125075120/http://www.volny.cz/iprenosil/interbase/ip_ib_strings.htm) (archived), that talks about some of the things to consider.

Comment: You really should not rip-off an entire article and post the text here.  It would be pretty poor form even if you had have included an attribution, which you did not.  Original here:  http://www.volny.cz/iprenosil/interbase/ip_ib_strings.htm

Comment: I agree with @APC.  A summary would be fine with the link, but don't just copy an entire article without giving proper attribution.

Comment: Thnax Bill for suggestion,will do the same form time ownwards

Comment: Hmm seems the link is gone, if you only would have copied the text, we could still read it :-)

Answer (score 2):

If by "messages" you mean something like SMS or IRC, stuff with a defined limit then I think VARCHAR is the most appropriate.  If your messages can really be any size then TEXT would be better.

But I wouldn't have thought BLOB was suitable for anything except perhaps attachments (assuming your system has them).   BLOBs are meant for binary files (e.g. images, Word documents) not pure text.