# How to store a blob (image) in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, base64, blob, intervention

I am using php and [intervention](http://image.intervention.io/)

What is the db format of a blob?

Is MySQL saving it as base64?

Before I save an image file to db what should I do?

```
Image::make('......')->encode('data-url');
```

Is that it?

Comment: blob stands for "Binary Large OBject". The data inserted should be binary, such as an image, not base64 encoded. You could use base64 to encode data while in transit, but it should be decoded when stored in a blob field.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn so if I provide a `File` parameter for the column it is OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How to store a Binary Large Object (BLOB)?**

- A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of
  data. The four BLOB types are `TINYBLOB`, `BLOB`, `MEDIUMBLOB`, and
  `LONGBLOB`.
- These differ only in the maximum length of the values they can hold.
- The four TEXT types are `TINYTEXT`, `TEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, and
  `LONGTEXT`. These correspond to the four BLOB types and have the same
  maximum    lengths and storage requirements.

Hope the following code will help you:

```
CREATE TABLE IMAGE_TABLE(
    IMG_ID INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    IMG_DETAILS CHAR(50),
    IMG_DATA LONGBLOB,
    IMG_NAME CHAR(50),
    IMG_SIZE CHAR(50),
    IMG_TYPE CHAR(50)
);
```

This will create a table which will suit your requirement.

You may also refer the following SO answers:

- [Binary Data in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17/binary-data-in-mysql)
- [store TEXT/BLOB in same table or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760998/store-text-blob-in-same-table-or-not)
- [Storing messages as BLOB (Binary Large Object) or ordinary text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208078/storing-messages-as-blob-binary-large-object-or-ordinary-text)

You can refer the [official documentation here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)  [This link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/) and [this link](http://mujweb.cz/iprenosil/interbase/ip_ib_strings.htm?redirected=1478163209) would be worth a read to deepen your understanding.